# JacksonPropertyNodeNameProvider not picking up the correct value When property is added in a custom Created Constraint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm using `JacksonPropertyNodeNameProvider` to render error with the actual json field name instead of the java class field name i.e `account_id` instead `accountId`. 
I added a custom Constraint as I want to validate on multiple fields. When I add a custom error

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("customField is a mandatory unique attribute")
            .addPropertyNode("customField").addBeanNode().addConstraintViolation();
```

It just returns `customField` in the error instead of custom_field. If I try to set the PropertNode to `custom_field` it errors with an ISE. Is there some configuration I need to set or something else I need to do to get this working? This is how I'm intializing my Validator.

```
@Bean
public Validator validator(@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    JacksonPropertyNodeNameProvider propertyNodeNameProvider = new JacksonPropertyNodeNameProvider(objectMapper);
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
            .configure()
            .propertyNodeNameProvider(propertyNodeNameProvider)
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this [way](https://github.com/dalibegovic/spring-validation-custom-property-name-support/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/validation/ValidationConfiguration.java) to customize the `PropertyNodeNameProvider`. I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.2 and I had no problems with `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter#getRejectedValue`. However, the way `PropertyNodeNameProvider` is customized could be improved, because when you generate a custom bean of `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, you lose the configurations made by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration`. You can remedy this by creating a proxy class of `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, but you will need to override all methods and delegate all calls to the original instance and this will make a verbose solution. I think that the best way to do that would be through an interface rather than a protected method inside `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean`, that way the customisation would be simple and the auto configurations made by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration` would not be lost. Do you think it's worth creating an issue for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have come up with right now is to Manually retrieve fieldNames before returning the response. It's a hacky solution but couldn't find a different approach. The reason being `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter#getRejectedValue` uses `getPropertyAccessor().getPropertyValue(field)` to get the rejected value and it needs to have exact fieldName for it to work.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler
    extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@Autowired
PropertyNodeNameProvider provider;

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(INVALID_INPUT.getType(), INVALID_INPUT.getMessage())
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(e -> {
        if (e instanceof FieldError) {
            FieldError fe = (FieldError) e;
            //Manually find the equivalent json property.
            var cv =  fe.unwrap(ConstraintViolationImpl.class);
            var field_name = provider.getName(new JavaBeanPropertyImpl(cv.getRootBeanClass(), fe.getField()));
            errorResponse.addError(field_name, fe.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    });
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, INVALID_INPUT.getStatus());
}


private static class JavaBeanPropertyImpl
        implements JavaBeanProperty {
    private final Class<?> declaringClass;
    private final String name;

    private JavaBeanPropertyImpl(Class<?> declaringClass, String name) {
        this.declaringClass = declaringClass;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getDeclaringClass() {
        return declaringClass;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

}